# Getting inconsistent results from dig

Tags: domain-name-system

I am trying to use dig, the bash command in Ubuntu 18.04LTS, to fetch all the txt records from a domain called *zhihu.com*, and it gives me inconsistent results.

The command I use is:

```
dig @8.8.8.8 SOA +short -t txt zhihu.com
```

This result looks good to me:

```
root@mx:/var/www/html/server# dig @8.8.8.8 SOA +short -t txt zhihu.com
;; Warning, extra type option
"m5g7qjk31l5d1hkq6m3zvcf6lg2f0h16"
"google-site-verification=q42VyLbU7bjRv5xb2279AX9jJ3Vuxp-e4XG_f1EQRGk"
"v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com include:cust-spf.edmsphere.com -all"
```

However, the next second I excute it, I get:

```
root@mx:/var/www/html/server# dig @8.8.8.8 SOA +short -t txt zhihu.com
;; Warning, extra type option
e4094fc1d98c915a.ksyunad.com.
```

And the `e4094fc1d98c915a.ksyunad.com` thing turns out to be a CNAME record value on *zhihu.com* in the DNS.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you are asking for both the `SOA` and `TXT` record. The `TXT` query is sent and a warning is issued.

The main problem is that the domain `zhihu.com` is misconfigured:

- since it is a delegated domain, it needs `SOA` and `NS` records,
- the existence of a `CNAME` record is not compatible with almost all other records (except DNSSEC)

Therefore you have an inconsistent behaviour: each DNS resolver can resolve that incompatibility as he wants. `8.8.8.8` is an anycast address: each time you connect with a potentially different server.

Comment: `since it is a top level domain` , a TLD is `.com` for example. `zhihu.com` is just a domain, certainly not a "top level" one.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek, what expression do you propose? _"delegated domain"_, _"start of authority domain"_? E.g. this problem does not concern `com.pl` and `co.uk` that could also be `CNAME`s.

Comment: `zhihu.com` is just a domain. Every node in the DNS, which is a tree, is a domain. The ones at "top", that is with only one level below the root (`.`) are called top-level, all others are just domains and in cases you really need to count for the depth, you will find sometimes "second-level domain", "third-level", etc. For all DNS terminologiy there is now an RFC: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8499.html

Comment: Yes, I agree, but the problem with adding a `CNAME` record to a domain, doesn't depend on the level of the domain, just whether it has the same authoritative nameservers or not. So, e.g.: `karwasz.org` can not be a `CNAME`, `www.karwasz.org` can, but a hypothetical `piotr.users.karwasz.org` can not if I delegate it to other nameservers. So my question is: which terminology would you agree to, in order to explain why `zhihu.com` can not be a `CNAME`. I find the usual explanation "second-level domains can not be `CNAME`'s confusing: e.g. `global.canon` can be a `CNAME`.

Comment: The domain is delegated from its parent. The presence of a dot is not automatically a sign of delegation. `karwasz.org` can be a CNAME in the `.org` zonefile... as long as it is not delegated. So it is not a problem of level in the tree, but a problem of being delegated or not.

Comment: I take this as you agree on the expression _"delegated domain"_ in my first comment.